# Sorting a list of strings not working. No idea what I'm doing wrong or how to fix

Tags: c#, winforms, list, sorting

I'm sorting a list of file names in alphabetical order however I get exception errors:

> Error1 'System.Collections.Generic.List' does not contain a definition for 'Length' and no extension method 'Length' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Now I'm suppose to understand how to implement this for next weeks class however I can't seem to get it to work. I understand the principals behind the sorting algorithm and am able to implement it using random integer values but when it comes to dealing with strings I'm kind of struggling.

Comment: It's hard to tell what the problem is without seeing the source that caused it.

Comment: Without seeing your code, I can tell you that lists have a `Count` property :)

Comment: Sorry guys, when I posted the code it didn't seem to keep the formatting.

Comment: Your error tells you everything you need to know. Please see my previous comment.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Thankyou so much! I'm still new to programming so not quite sure how to figure out what the error messages mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.Count` instead of `.Length`.  They do the same thing, but one is for lists, and the other is for arrays.